# "Plug-in container failed" error when playing Flash game in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

I cannot use Firefox to play Zynga poker on Facebook anymore. It freezes and becomes unresponsive.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.18 on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 with Flash version 10.3.187.3.

I get the error: "plug-in container failed". Here are the details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: plugin-container.exe
  Application Version:  1.9.2.4182
  Application Timestamp:    4df86355
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7ba58
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000222c2
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Answer (score 1):

You *really* **really** should update your firefox. And when that is done make sure you have the latest flash version installed.

You can read all about your problem on this mozilla support page :[The Adobe Flash plugin has crashed](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/The%20Adobe%20Flash%20plugin%20has%20crashed)